# Tornado Asynchronous Writes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

The code below is a simplified version of a Tornado based TCP server that is currently used to host a Videotex system. This code was derived from the Tornado documentation and the server has been running in a live environment for some time without issue, however, there is a feature I need to add.

The system currently blocks until a character is received from the client before returning the data via the stream.write. As the system typically runs at 1200 baud at the client end (via a telnet modem), this means that the user has to wait until all stream writes have completed before the next 'user entered' character is processed.

What I would like to do is find a way that would allow me to abandon writing data to stream.write if another character is received form the client.

I am new to Tornado and fairly new to Python, however, I have coded asynchronous functions and threaded solutions in the past using C#.

From the documentation the stream.write operation is asynchronous, I am assuming therefore that the call may return before the data is completely written, I am left thinking that I need a method to abandon/empty/advance the write buffer to stop the write operation if a new char is detected on the stream.read.

One option that would seem to give me what I need is to somehow perform the stream.writes on another thread , however, this approach seems inappropriate when using Tornado's IOLoop etc.

Is there a way to give me the facility I am after? I have full control of the code and am happy to restructure the app if needed.

```
import logging
import struct
import os
import traceback

from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer

# Configure logging.
logger = logging.getLogger(os.path.basename(__file__))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Cache this struct definition; important optimization.
int_struct = struct.Struct("<i")
_UNPACK_INT = int_struct.unpack
_PACK_INT = int_struct.pack


class TornadoServer(TCPServer):

    def start(self, port):

        self.port = port
        server.listen(port)

    @gen.coroutine
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):

        logging.info("[viewdata] Connection from client address {0}.".format(address))
        try:

            while True:

                char = yield stream.read_bytes(1) # this call blocks

                asc = ord(char)
                logger.info('[viewdata] Byte Received {0} ({1})'.format(hex(asc), asc))

                # Do some processing using the received char and return the appropriate page of data
                stream.write('This is the data you asked for...'.encode())

        except StreamClosedError as ex:
            logger.info("[viewdata] {0} Disconnected: {1} Message: {2}".format(address, type(ex), str(ex)))
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error("[viewdata] {0} Exception: {1} Message: {2}".format(address, type(ex), str(ex)))
            logger.error(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    server = TornadoServer()
    server.start(25232)

    loop = IOLoop.current()
    loop.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that you move long processing into separate task.
When you receive some new data, you choose what to do (in case below I cancel current operation)

```
import logging
import os
import traceback

import threading
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer

# Configure logging.
logger = logging.getLogger(os.path.basename(__file__))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class TornadoServer(TCPServer):

    def start(self, port):

        self.port = port
        server.listen(port)

    async def process_stream(self, stream, char, cancel_event):
        asc = ord(char)
        logger.info('[viewdata] Byte Received {0} ({1})'.format(hex(asc), asc))
        N = 5
        for i in range(N):
            if cancel_event.is_set():
                logger.info('[viewdata] Abort streaming')
                break
            # Do some processing using the received char and return the appropriate page of data
            msg = 'This is the {0} data you asked for...'.format(i)
            logger.info(msg)
            await stream.write('This is the part {0} of {1} you asked for...'.format(i, N).encode())
            await gen.sleep(1.0)  # make this processing longer..


    async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):

        process_stream_future = None
        cancel_event = None

        logging.info("[viewdata] Connection from client address {0}.".format(address))
        while True:
            try:

                char = await stream.read_bytes(1)  # this call blocks

                # when received client input, cancel running job
                if process_stream_future:
                    process_stream_future.cancel()
                if cancel_event:
                    cancel_event.set()

                cancel_event = threading.Event()
                process_stream_future = gen.convert_yielded(
                    self.process_stream(stream, char, cancel_event))
                self.io_loop.add_future(process_stream_future, lambda f: f.result())

            except StreamClosedError as ex:
                logger.info("[viewdata] {0} Disconnected: {1} Message: {2}".format(address, type(ex), str(ex)))
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.error("[viewdata] {0} Exception: {1} Message: {2}".format(address, type(ex), str(ex)))
                logger.error(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    server = TornadoServer()
    server.listen(25232)

    loop = IOLoop.current()
    loop.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have this example working. I am new to python so please forgive me if this seems like a stupid question... I notice that the stream object is passed to the process_stream method and wondered if this needed some form of locking mechanism? or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: You don't need extra locking - [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) protects you.